# Como usar 0.001 no phyton?

Tags: python

Quando tento fazer a operação D243600GV/0.001 aparece essa mensagem : leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integer

O que devo fazer??

Comment: Importante editar a [primeira postagem que fez sobre o assunto](/q/584170/70) conforme já orientado lá. Para evitar desencontro e/ou redundância de infomações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode se usado na postagem original.